# How to order a Many2many field (tree view) by some field?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-8, odoo

I have just realised that users cannot order a `Many2many` field through the interface like a `One2many` field.

In standard `One2many` fields, you see the tree view of the comodel with its fields. If you click on the name of a field (name of the column) of the `One2many`, its tree view is automatically ordered by the field which you clicked on (if this field is stored in the database), and you see a small arrow icon.

But in standard `Many2many` fields, if you click on the name of any column (it does not matter that the field is stored in the database), it does nothing, you cannot order its tree view.

In fact, XML tree attribute `default_order` does not seem to work if the tree is opened inside a `Many2many`.

The only thing that is still working is `_order` if I add it to the Python definition of the comodel.

For example:

I have a `Many2many` field pointing to `account.treasury.forecast.invoice`. I don't tell the field to open any specific view, so the following tree view is loaded by default:

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="account_treasury_forecast_invoice_tree_view">
    <field name="name">account.treasury.forecast.invoice.tree</field>
    <field name="model">account.treasury.forecast.invoice</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Invoices" widget="many2many">
            <field name="date_due" />
            <field name="invoice_id" />
            <field name="partner_id"/>
            <field name="journal_id" />
            <field name="base_amount" sum="Total Base" />
            <field name="tax_amount" sum="Total Taxes" />
            <field name="total_amount" sum="Total" />
            <field name="residual_amount" sum="Total Residual" />
            <field name="state" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

I have realised that `default_order` does nothing if the following view is opened in a `Many2many` field.

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="account_treasury_forecast_invoice_tree_view">
    <field name="name">account.treasury.forecast.invoice.tree</field>
    <field name="model">account.treasury.forecast.invoice</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Invoices" widget="many2many" default_order="date_due">
            <field name="date_due" />
            <field name="invoice_id" />
            <field name="partner_id"/>
            <field name="journal_id" />
            <field name="base_amount" sum="Total Base" />
            <field name="tax_amount" sum="Total Taxes" />
            <field name="total_amount" sum="Total" />
            <field name="residual_amount" sum="Total Residual" />
            <field name="state" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

And at least `_order` works:

```
class AccountTreasuryForecastInvoice(models.Model):
    _name = 'account.treasury.forecast.invoice'
    _description = 'Treasury Forecast Invoice'
    _order = 'date_due'
```

But the problem is that the interface does not allow users to order by any of its fields, and I want to allow them to order sometimes by `date_due` and sometimes by `invoice_id`. How can I manage that? Do you experience the same issue with `Many2many` fields?